# Как проверить JsonElement на пустоту

Tags: c#

Как правильно проверить `JsonElement` на пустоту - значение по умолчанию ?

[System.Text.Json JsonElement Структура](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=netcore-3.1)

```
        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonElement();

        if (jsonElement.ToString() == String.Empty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Пустое");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Не пустое");
        }
```

**ЗЫ** Один из методов возвращает `JsonElement` и хотелось бы знать, как правильно проверить значение на то, что оно не дефолтное, до того, как начать взаимодействовать с ним.

Comment: Этот код разве не работает? Для какого `ValueKind` вы выполняете проверку?

Comment: @aepot этот вариант прекрасно работает, вот только мне показалось немного странным так проверять и хотелось более правильное решение найти.

Comment: Правильное решение зависит от требований к этому решению, строка может быть пустой, а может быть `null`, а может содержать только пробелы. Число может быть `0`, может быть `null` и так далее для всех `ValueKind`. Вообще парсить поэлементно - неблагодарное занятие, используйте сериализацию/десерализацию.

Comment: @aepot такс, значит дефолтное значение зависит от `ValueKind`, в моём случае я имею только `ValueKind - Object`, ну и `ValueKind - Undefined` если он пустой. А по поводу `десериализации`, понимаю, но я пытаюсь отловить неизвестные мне ключи которые периодически вылезают чтобы достроить класс.

Comment: Можно проще https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763919/12888024 - закидывать в словарь только неизвестные поля. Там пример для Newtonsoft.Json, но в System.Text.Json есть точно такой же аттрибут, и используется он точно так же с словарем `<string, JsonElement>`

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-handle-overflow?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое! изучу